# Pentaho HBase Import: Pull from HBase with Date data type throwing error

Tags: type-conversion, hbase, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to query hbase using HBase input step. but it is throwing me error "HBase input 2.0 - The length of a date column value must equal that of a long"

below is the screen shots of my configuration
[image]
[image]

This is the data I have in my HBase table
[image]

You can see messageTimestamp is a string of numbers. I want to filter query on this column like
[image]

but this throws me an error which I suspects is related to type casting.

```
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Unexpected error  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - Unable to execute source table scan  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@75d93487  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 -  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - at org.pentaho.big.data.kettle.plugins.hbase.input.HBaseInput.processRow(HBaseInput.java:245)  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@75d93487  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - at com.pentaho.big.data.bundles.impl.shim.hbase.table.ResultScannerBuilderImpl$3.perform(ResultScannerBuilderImpl.java:109)  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - at com.pentaho.big.data.bundles.impl.shim.hbase.BatchHBaseConnectionOperation.perform(BatchHBaseConnectionOperation.java:45)  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - at com.pentaho.big.data.bundles.impl.shim.hbase.table.ResultScannerBuilderImpl.build(ResultScannerBuilderImpl.java:126)  
2019/04/26 11:56:05 - HBase input 2.0 - at org.pentaho.big.data.kettle.plugins.hbase.input.HBaseInput.processRow(HBaseInput.java:243)
```

if I remove filter and try to pull complete table. I still gets below error

```
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Unexpected error  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException:  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - The length of a date column value must equal that of a long  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 -  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - at org.pentaho.hbase.shim.api.HBaseValueMeta.decodeColumnValue(HBaseValueMeta.java:755)  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - at com.pentaho.big.data.bundles.impl.shim.hbase.meta.HBaseValueMetaInterfaceImpl.decodeColumnValue(HBaseValueMetaInterfaceImpl.java:49)  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - at org.pentaho.big.data.kettle.plugins.hbase.input.HBaseInputData.getOutputRow(HBaseInputData.java:281)  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - at org.pentaho.big.data.kettle.plugins.hbase.input.HBaseInput.processRow(HBaseInput.java:287)  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:62)  
2019/04/26 11:59:46 - HBase input 2.0 - at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea what causing this error.